# How to make two different divs width same , in different screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have Two Div, class name .div1 & .div2 with width:20%; each. Inside .div1 I have a another div name .bar

This .bar div is positioned left 100% absolute. I am trying to make the End point of .bar div and End point of .div2 should remain in same point in different screen like this Image below:
[image]

You can see that End point of Green Bar(.bar) and Gay Div(.div2) are in Line. But if I increase or decrease the size of the screen they don't remain in line. I have tied many ways but not worked. Is this possible with only CSS ? or Need any jQuery help ? If need any jQuery can anyone help me how to do that ? because I am not good with jQuery.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="div1">
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">

    </div>
```

This is CSS that I have used:

```
.div1{
background:red;
}
.div2{
     background:#ccc;
     margin-top:25px !important;
}
.div1,.div2{
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px;
    height:180px;
}
.bar{
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
    height:20px;
    left:100%;
    top:0px;
    width:114%;
    z-index:10;

}
```

Thanks in advance. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/97s283he/5/)**

Comment: The "bar" div width is 114%.20% + 10px might not be the same as 114% of the 20% of the page.

Comment: What can be done then ?

Comment: If you want things to stay positioned relative to screen widths you need to use percentages. You cannot mix percentages and pixels. Try this fiddle. I just killed off the margins on the .div1,.div2 and added a percentage margin to .div2. Note that you'll need to do your own calculations, depending on what exactly you need. http://jsfiddle.net/97s283he/6/

Comment: Thanks this is almost the point. This div1 & div2 representing bootstrap you know. They have padding 15px left and right.